# Python combining if statements with "and" giving statement expected error

Tags: python, numpy

This statement:

```
        if 0 not in np.where(~mat.any(axis=1))[0].tolist() and \
            if 0 not in np.where(~mat.any(axis=0))[0].tolist():
            filled_both = True
```

is giving me an error but each on their own seems fine.  What am I doing wrong?
This ran without problems:

```
        if 0 not in np.where(~mat.any(axis=1))[0].tolist():
            if 0 not in np.where(~mat.any(axis=0))[0].tolist():
                filled_both = True
```

Comment: You either use a second `if` or `and`. You can join conditions, not `if` statements.

Comment: `if statements` can't follow `and`

Comment: You either want two 'ifs' and no 'and', or one 'if' and one 'and.  `if 0 not in xxx and 0 not in yyy:`

Comment: So you got a "statement expected error". I haven't seen that before in python. When I tried it, I got a syntax error.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Go back to the tutorial on Boolean expressions, and learn how to use `and` and `or`.  The basic problem is in your title: there **is** no `and` operator for statements.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `and`, you shouldn't/can't use another `if` after it. They're mutually exclusive constructs (`if ...:` is a statement where `...` is an expression to evaluate for truth; `and` joins two expressions to make a new expression, one that might be used in an `if`). Your first bit of code should be:

```
if 0 not in np.where(~mat.any(axis=1))[0].tolist() and \
   0 not in np.where(~mat.any(axis=0))[0].tolist():
    filled_both = True
```

with the `if` on the second line removed.